# Salesforce to Outlook API

Tags: api, connect-for-outlook

We use outlook-2010 version, doesn't support "lightning sync" or "Lightning for Outlook".

"Salesforce to Outlook plug-in" is not a great solution for us.

If possible, would like to build custom API to connect with Outlook calendar and get the events information into Salesforce.

Is it possible ? and any direction/guidance is highly appreciated.